# How do I access specific columns in a pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called p_assets_df that looks like this:

```
                      <close>      <high>    <low>      <open>  <vol>
<date>   <ticker>                                                    
20110101 AEDCAD        0.2707      0.2715   0.2707      0.2715      0
         AEDCHF        0.2545      0.2545   0.2545      0.2545      0
         AEDDKK        1.4950      1.5262   1.4950      1.5262      0
         AEDEUR        0.2006      0.2047   0.2006      0.2047      0
         AEDGBP        0.1747      0.1759   0.1747      0.1759      0
         AEDINR       12.1320     12.1320  12.1320     12.1320      0
         AEDJPY       22.1160     22.1550  22.1160     22.1550      0
         AEDNZD        0.3495      0.3514   0.3495      0.3514      0
         AEDPKR       23.3050     23.3170  23.3050     23.3170      0
20110102 AEDZAR        1.7914      1.8020   1.7864      1.8020      0
         ARSAUD        0.2476      0.2478   0.2424      0.2424      0
         ARSBRL        0.4181      0.4181   0.4114      0.4114      0
         ARSCAD        0.2512      0.2516   0.2475      0.2475      0
         ARSCHF        0.2360      0.2364   0.2310      0.2310      0
         ARSEUR        0.1894      0.1894   0.1852      0.1852      0
         ARSGBP        0.1625      0.1625   0.1589      0.1589      0
         ARSHKD        1.9653      1.9662   1.9280      1.9280      0
         ARSJPY       20.5260      20.5530  20.1270     20.1270      0
```

I am trying to add a new column called 'Rolling Average' that uses the  column value to calculate the moving average for each ticker symbol. This is a multi-index df with the date as the first index and the ticker as the second index.

I've tried doing this:

Here is the code that I've tried.

```py
    p_assets_df['Rolling_Average'] = 
    p_assets_df.groupby(level=0).rolling(window=26) 
    ['<close>'].mean().values
```

I've also set the level value to 1 and to [0,1] with no change.

The problem I'm having is that the rolling average only returns NaN's all the way down the new column.  I would expect NaN's for the first x values as supplied in the window parameter, but not for every value in the column. Note that the first index goes from 20110101 to 20111231 with a daily frequency.
Here is the tail() method output.

```
20111230 AEDCAD     0.2776   0.2780   0.2776   0.2780      0              NaN
         AEDCHF     0.2555   0.2559   0.2555   0.2559      0              NaN
         AEDDKK     1.5606   1.5637   1.5606   1.5620      0              NaN
         AEDEUR     0.2100   0.2103   0.2100   0.2101      0              NaN
         AEDGBP     0.1763   0.1766   0.1763   0.1766      0              NaN
         AEDINR    14.4260  14.5180  14.4020  14.4290      0              NaN
         AEDJPY    21.0730  21.1350  21.0730  21.1350      0              NaN
         AEDNZD     0.3519   0.3529   0.3519   0.3529      0              NaN
         AEDPKR    24.4340  24.4340  24.4210  24.4210      0              NaN
20111231 AEDCAD     0.2768   0.2768   0.2768   0.2768      0              NaN
         AEDCHF     0.2553   0.2553   0.2553   0.2553      0              NaN
         AEDDKK     1.5590   1.5590   1.5590   1.5590      0              NaN
         AEDEUR     0.2097   0.2097   0.2097   0.2097      0              NaN
         AEDGBP     0.1755   0.1755   0.1755   0.1755      0              NaN
         AEDINR    14.4260  14.4260  14.4260  14.4260      0              NaN
         AEDJPY    20.9620  20.9620  20.9620  20.9620      0              NaN
         AEDNZD     0.3493   0.3493   0.3493   0.3493      0              NaN
         AEDPKR    24.4480  24.4480  24.4480  24.4480      0              NaN
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `level=1` and for correct align output add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by first level with `drop=True` for remove it instead `.values`:

```
p_assets_df['Rolling_Average'] = (p_assets_df.groupby(level=1)
                                             .rolling(window=26)['<close>']
                                             .mean()
                                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Test with `window=2` for sample data from question:

```
p_assets_df['Rolling_Average'] = (p_assets_df.groupby(level=1)
                                             .rolling(window=2)['<close>']
                                             .mean()
                                             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

---

```
print (p_assets_df)
                   <close>   <high>    <low>   <open>  <vol>  Rolling_Average
<date>   <ticker>                                                            
20110101 AEDCAD     0.2707   0.2715   0.2707   0.2715      0              NaN
         AEDCHF     0.2545   0.2545   0.2545   0.2545      0              NaN
         AEDDKK     1.4950   1.5262   1.4950   1.5262      0              NaN
         AEDEUR     0.2006   0.2047   0.2006   0.2047      0              NaN
         AEDGBP     0.1747   0.1759   0.1747   0.1759      0              NaN
         AEDINR    12.1320  12.1320  12.1320  12.1320      0              NaN
         AEDJPY    22.1160  22.1550  22.1160  22.1550      0              NaN
         AEDNZD     0.3495   0.3514   0.3495   0.3514      0              NaN
         AEDPKR    23.3050  23.3170  23.3050  23.3170      0              NaN
20110102 AEDZAR     1.7914   1.8020   1.7864   1.8020      0              NaN
         ARSAUD     0.2476   0.2478   0.2424   0.2424      0              NaN
         ARSBRL     0.4181   0.4181   0.4114   0.4114      0              NaN
         ARSCAD     0.2512   0.2516   0.2475   0.2475      0              NaN
         ARSCHF     0.2360   0.2364   0.2310   0.2310      0              NaN
         ARSEUR     0.1894   0.1894   0.1852   0.1852      0              NaN
         ARSGBP     0.1625   0.1625   0.1589   0.1589      0              NaN
         ARSHKD     1.9653   1.9662   1.9280   1.9280      0              NaN
         ARSJPY    20.5260  20.5530  20.1270  20.1270      0              NaN
20111230 AEDCAD     0.2776   0.2780   0.2776   0.2780      0          0.27415
         AEDCHF     0.2555   0.2559   0.2555   0.2559      0          0.25500
         AEDDKK     1.5606   1.5637   1.5606   1.5620      0          1.52780
         AEDEUR     0.2100   0.2103   0.2100   0.2101      0          0.20530
         AEDGBP     0.1763   0.1766   0.1763   0.1766      0          0.17550
         AEDINR    14.4260  14.5180  14.4020  14.4290      0         13.27900
         AEDJPY    21.0730  21.1350  21.0730  21.1350      0         21.59450
         AEDNZD     0.3519   0.3529   0.3519   0.3529      0          0.35070
         AEDPKR    24.4340  24.4340  24.4210  24.4210      0         23.86950
20111231 AEDCAD     0.2768   0.2768   0.2768   0.2768      0          0.27720
         AEDCHF     0.2553   0.2553   0.2553   0.2553      0          0.25540
         AEDDKK     1.5590   1.5590   1.5590   1.5590      0          1.55980
         AEDEUR     0.2097   0.2097   0.2097   0.2097      0          0.20985
         AEDGBP     0.1755   0.1755   0.1755   0.1755      0          0.17590
         AEDINR    14.4260  14.4260  14.4260  14.4260      0         14.42600
         AEDJPY    20.9620  20.9620  20.9620  20.9620      0         21.01750
         AEDNZD     0.3493   0.3493   0.3493   0.3493      0          0.35060
         AEDPKR    24.4480  24.4480  24.4480  24.4480      0         24.44100
```